# How to merge more that one array into an array using Objective C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Obj-C, how can I append one NSMutableArray to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9471713/obj-c-how-can-i-append-one-nsmutablearray-to-another)

I want to put the contents of more than one array into an array. Can Anyone tell me how to do this using Objective C.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray *newArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[newArray addObjectsFromArray:firstArray];

[newArray addObjectsFromArray:secondArray];

...
```

-Ole-

Comment: And to extract the objects in the arrays: `[[newArray objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:0];`

Answer (score 1):

NSMutableArray has a `[array addObjects: fromArray:]` method i believe. Check the docs.

Answer (score 1):

Use `addObjects: fromArray:` method of `NSMutableArray`. If you need to merge several arrays - just call method several times