# Obj-C, how can I append one NSMutableArray to another?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

How can I append one NSMutableArray to another, from what I've seen, it sound be fairly straight forward. But I'm getting some weird results, I think the amount of items in my temp array are being added but the dictionary values are being lost.

This is my current code, where I just overwrite my self.transactionArray

```
h - file
NSMutableArray *transactionArray;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *transactionArray;

m - file
NSMutableArray *arrayTmp= [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

//start loop
[arrayTmp addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:desc,@"desc",
         due,@"due",nil]];  
//release nsstring desc etc
//end loop

self.transactionArray = arrayTmp;

[arrayTmp release];
```

My second attempt...

```
NSMutableArray *array1 = [arrayTmp mutableCopy];
[self.transactionArray addObjectFromArray:array1];
```

This was my first attempt...

```
[self.transactionArray addObjectFromArray:arrayTmp];
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that like this:

```
[self.transactionArray addObjectsFromArray:arrayTmp];
```

And on a side note, please always read the documentation before posting a question. This method is easily found in the [`NSMutableArray`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html) documentation.

Comment: It sounds like transactionArray is an `NSArray`, so I don't think that will work.

Comment: He says he wants to append one `NSMutableArray` to another. That implies that they're both mutable.

Comment: He's only adding one object, and he used `addObject:` correctly in the first example, which led me to believe that there was something preventing him using that method on the original array.

Comment: Typo, meant I had tried `[self.transactionArray addObjectsFromArray:arrayTmp];` ... I think the amount of items in ...

Comment: @edc1591 yes they are both NSMutableArray

Comment: @Jules Then why not just add the object directly to `self.transactionArray`?

Comment: @Jules Could it be a problem with the autorelease pool? There aren't any objects that you want to stick around still in the pool when the loop is through, are there?

Answer (score 0):

You may have a typo. Look at the [`NSMutableArray` method](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

```
- (void)addObjectsFromArray:(NSArray *)otherArray
```

Comment: Tried `[self.transactionArray addObjectsFromArray:arrayTmp];`

Comment: "But I'm getting some weird results, I think the amount of items in my temp array are being added but the dictionary values are being lost."

Comment: @Jules Try printing the contents of the arrays to the console before and after calling these methods, e.g. `NSLog(@"%@",array)`. This should help you to diagnose the problem better.